# Configuring database change notification to get only newly inserted or updated data in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, spring-integration

I am building an application that does some processing after looking up a database (oracle).

Currently, I have configured the application with Spring Integration and it polls data in a periodic fashion regardless of whether any data is updated or inserted.

The problem here is, I cannot add or use any column to distinguish between old and new records. Also, for no insert or update in table as well, poller polls data from database and feeds the data into message channel.

For that, I want to switch to database change notification and I need to register the query something like

```
 SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE STATUS='ACTIVE'
```

now this active status is true for old and new entries and I want to eliminate the old entries from my list. So that, only after a new insert or an existing update, I want to get data which are added newly or updated recently.

Comment: Can you put one column as lastupdatedatetime and then query on this column, whenever you poll for all records with lastupdatedatetime greater than lasttime code did polling. This logic will return only last window inserted or updated records. Also I would suggest to use version number or flag in your tables, whenever any record is inserted/updated then increment that version number or make version flag as true and make old version of record as false.

Comment: Thanks Amit, but as I said, I can not add any extra column to the table so that I can identify in this straight forward way, my question was, is there any other approach to the same?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is really very sad that you can't modify the data model in the database. I'd really suggest to try to insist to change the table for your convenience. For example might really be just one more column `LAST_MODIFIED`, so could to filter the old records and only poll those which date is very fresh.

There is also possibility in Oracle like `trigger`, so you can perform some action on INSERT/UPDATE and modify some other table for your interest.

Otherwise you don't have choice unless use one more extra persistence service to track loaded records. For example `MetadataStore` based on Redis or MongoDB: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store